# MariaDB Docker Start Fails

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying to start MariaDB with Docker 1.13.1.

```
docker run -d --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306   -p 4567:4567/udp   -p 4567-4568:4567-4568   -p 4444:4444   -v /mnt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mariadb:10.1 chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && mysqld --user=mysql --wsrep-new-cluster
```

I get the following output after starting:

```
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.23-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 6 ...
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 12 MB
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2017-05-11 20:04:55 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45883
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.35-80.0 started; log sequence number 0
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780029413120 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-05-11 20:04:56 139780804880320 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

The mysql user owns the directory and is able to create the ibdata1 and related files. I can't figure out if it's failing to create other tables and/or why it's failing to read them?

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
docker run -d --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306   -p 4567:4567/udp   -p 4567-4568:4567-4568   -p 4444:4444   -v /mnt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mariadb:10.1 /bin/bash -c 'chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && mysqld --user=mysql --wsrep-new-cluster'
```

The problem is that everything after the `&&` is not inserted as command line inside the container but outside, in the host shell, unless properly quoted as an argument to the `-c` option of /bin/bash (/bin/sh is valid too).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my startup script that ran as part of my ENTRYPOINT in the docker image:

```
chmod -R ug+rw /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

This way, I avoided all the volume mounting and simply could use the read-write layer in my normal container.  This is building a developer container for an open source project so I am trying to make a container that is all-in-one for my developers to use.   There might be a cleaner way to solve this - but this worked for me.